# How to find the polar set?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

> Let $$A = \left\{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y \geq x^2 +c, \, c \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$$ Find the polar set for $A$.

My attempts: 
$(u, v) \in \mathbb{R}^2; l(x, y) := ux+vy, \partial A: t \rightarrow (x(t), y(t)) = ( ct, \sqrt{c}t).$ I'm trying to find max of $f(t) = l(x(t), y(t)) = uct+v\sqrt{c}t$. But it is $\infty$. Help me please!

Comment: I don't understand, is $c$ fixed? If it isn't, then $A$ is just the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$, no?

Comment: @TSF yes, c is fixed. It is some constant

Comment: It's not $\infty$ if $c=0$. Polar sets are very sensitive to translation.

Comment: @TSF but we don't know is c= 0 or not. It some fixed number. Not necessarily a zero.

Comment: I understand that, what I am trying to demonstrate is that the polar set will depend on $c$ in a nontrivial way. For example, whether or not the set contains the origin is very important.

Comment: @TeXminator can you consider my question, please? When I was trying to find similar question I saw your answers for tag convex-analysis.